# Running javascript loop, asynchronous results

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops, asynchronous

I got 50 JSON files. (1.json, 2.json ... 50.json).
The structure for each one is:

```
{
  "book": "Księga Wyjścia",
  "chapter": 1,
  "type": "verses",
  "verses": [
    {
      "text": "Oto imiona synów Izraela, którzy razem z Jakubem przybyli do Egiptu. Każdy zaś przyszedł ze swoją rodziną:",
      "verse": "1"
    },
    {
      "text": "Ruben, Symeon, Lewi, Juda;",
      "verse": "2"
    },
    {
      "text": "Issachar, Zabulon i Beniamin;",
      "verse": "3"
    },
    {
      "text": "Dan, Neftali, Gad i Aser.",
      "verse": "4"
    },
    {
      "text": "Było zaś wszystkich potomków Jakuba siedemdziesiąt osób, Józef zaś już był w Egipcie.",
      "verse": "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

There are more verses in every file and the size of each one can be completely different (so they don't load immediately).
I load "chapter" node. Each time I refresh the file, I got different order, ie. (just last few numbers from last reshresh): 28,35,32,36,37,29,30,31,38,33,49,50,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48

```html
<script>
  for (i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var input = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(input.chapter);

      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", (i + ".json"), true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
</script>
```

I assume it's because it loads asynchronous. Can I force my script to load synchronous?

Comment: I would certainly not advise to pass `false` as value for the *async* argument. Embrace the power of promises and asynchronous programming instead.

Comment: I would suggest attempting to use the result of the requests in a way that does not rely on order. Is that a possibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `fetch` API and the power of promises:

```
let promises = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
    promises.push(fetch(i + ".json").then(resp => resp.json());
}
Promise.all(promises).then(function(inputs) {
    inputs.forEach(input => console.log(input.chapter));
});
```

Even though the promises may resolve in a different order, `Promise.all` will resolve to an array of responses that maintains the original order of the promises it got.

NB: make sure you define your variables (like `i`) with `var`, `let` or `const`

Comment: I think this is too advanced for OP however since, you're down that road, may I suggest to chunk the outrageous 50 async requests to maybe 5 at a time? :)

Comment: The OP already did those simultaneous requests at the same time and apparently without a problem.

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar `fetch` is the standard therefor I can't consider this is advanced. Actually it's much easier than XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: @MoshFeu I am not calling `fetch` advanced but, I was referring to the usage of Promise API and Promises in general. It may solve the current issue that the OP is facing but, might have a hard time integrating it with something else. **Note** I'm assuming that OP is a beginner.

Comment: Well, it makes more sense. Even though, I think that `XMLHttpRequest` is more complicated and really shouldn't be in use in 2020. IMHO of course :)

Comment: And once you say fetch, you say promises.

Comment: @trincot That's exactly why I said, *the usage of Promise API and Promises **in general*** ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the requests **asynchronous** *because not only it would save the loading time but, **if any of the requests take too long to respond, no other chapter will be loaded until that request resolves.***

As a start, I would suggest you create a `responses` array and in the callback, push the JSON response to that array and check for the number of `responses` received so far, *when the number responses are 50, it means all of the chapters are loaded. At that point, `sort()` the `responses` based on `chapter`.* **Once done, you will then be able to go ahead and `doSomething()`**.

**Note:** You need to define `doSomething()` function that takes all of the chapters in order as an input and does something with them.

```
<script>
var responses = [];

for (i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var input = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            responses.push(input);

            if (responses.length === 50) {
                responses = responses.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return a.chapter < b.chapter;
                });
                doSomething(responses);
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", (i + ".json"), true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Like @MoshFeu and @trincot suggested, it is way easier to use `fetch` and if you get your head around `Promise`, you will be far better off with `Promise` and `async/await` syntax for all the asynchronous work.